# Case when within a union?

Tags: sql, select, union, case

Here's my code:

```
SELECT 'Add or remove a keyword' AS 'Keyword', '1' AS 'row number'
UNION
SELECT '---------------------', '2'
UNION
SELECT 
   CASE
   WHEN @list_item = 'duration'
   THEN (SELECT duration FROM durationTable)
   END
   CASE
   WHEN @list_item = 'location'
   THEN (SELECT location FROM locationTable)
   END
, '3'
ORDER BY 2
```

The trouble is, this sees the duration and location selects as subqueries, and subqueries are limited to only one result, and furthermore, I can't seem to figure out the correct syntax to bump my CASE up a level so the queries aren't subqueries.

Is there a way that I can keep the structure that the union / select allows me, while also changing up which table is queried for the last bit, and also retrieving the entire table column instead of one result?

Any tips? Thank you so much for taking a look!

Answer (score 2):

First, you should know this is a bad design.  You are mixing up your presentation layer and your data layer and it will lead to problems down the road.

However, if you are absolutely committed to doing this, you can do it with an additional `SELECT`:

```
...
UNION

SELECT duration FROM durationTable, '3'
WHERE @list_item = 'duration'

UNION

SELECT location FROM locationTable, '3'
WHERE @list_item = 'location'
...
```

The non-matching query will return an empty result set and be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

It's not pretty, but I think this should work:

```
SELECT 'Add or remove a keyword' AS 'Keyword', '1' AS 'row number'
UNION
SELECT '---------------------', '2'
UNION
SELECT duration, '3' FROM durationTable WHERE 1 = (SELECT CASE WHEN @list_item = 'duration' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
UNION
SELECT location, '3' FROM locationTable WHERE 1 = (SELECT CASE WHEN @list_item = 'location' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

Comment: Why did you use a `CASE` instead of just a `WHERE` clause?

Comment: @JNK, you are right, I should have just used a simple WHERE clause instead of complicating it with a CASE. I have upvoted your answer, since it is the better solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 'Add or remove a keyword' AS 'Keyword', '1' AS 'row number'
UNION
SELECT '---------------------', '2'
UNION
SELECT duration,3 FROM durationTable WHERE @list_item = 'duration'
UNION
SELECT location,3 FROM locationTable WHERE @list_item = 'location'
```